# Help with an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone help me with the process needed to integrate this?

$$\int_2^x \frac{\ln{(y-1)}}{\ln{(y)}} dy$$

Thank you!

Comment: what kind of $$\log$$ is this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It doesn't matter since the logarithm base divides out of both top and bottom.

Comment: Wolframalpha says “no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions”; note that “standard” includes several transcendental functions.

Comment: Would you be interested in a series expansion of the solution?  Closed form is hard to nail down.

Comment: @egreg I had already tried Mathematica with no result

Comment: @user3141592 I cannot expect a solution to exist.  Even for just $x=3$ wolfram returns no closed form for the value.

Comment: @Simple Everything helps, but I would be very interested on finding a closed form. Why is it as hard to find? Isn't this a common integral?

Comment: Nope.  Logarithms in the denominator are far from simple.  Se the logarithmic integral for example.

Comment: It's worth noting that Wolfram Alpha uses numeral integration to approximate the result, suggesting that there is no closed form.

Comment: @Simple Then, would it be possible to leave it in terms of the logarithmic integral? And how would be its series expansion?

Comment: A lot of problems with $y=0$ prevent me from doing anything simple, sorry.

Comment: @Simple Don't worry, thank you. Where could I find more information about it?

Comment: The logarithmic integral?  I'd just google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple leaves the antiderivative unevaluated.  Since this is the pure transcendental case, I think Maple's implementation of the Risch algorithm should be trustworthy, leading to the conclusion that this is not an elementary function.

EDIT: The change of variables $y = e^t$ makes the integral into

$$ J(t) = \int \ln(e^t-1) \dfrac{e^t}{t} \; dt $$

For $t > 0 $ we have

$$ \ln(e^t-1) = t + \ln(1 - e^{-t}) =  t - \sum_{j=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-jt}}{j} $$

and then integrating term-by-term, your antiderivative becomes 
$$ J(t) = e^t - \ln(t) - \sum_{j=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{j+1} \text{Ei}(-jt) + C$$

Comment: And what about a series expansion? Or would it be possible to leave it in terms of the logatirhmic integral?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an elementary integral, but it is not that difficult to approximate since
$$ \int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log(y-1)}{\log y}\,dy = (x-2)\color{blue}{-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{1}{y}\right)}{\log y}\,dy} $$
and the last integral has the same magnitude of
$$ \int_{2}^{x}\frac{dy}{y\log y} = \log\log(x)-\log\log(2),$$
so
$$ \int_{2}^{x}\frac{\log(y-1)}{\log y}\,dy = x-\log\log(x)+O(1).$$

Comment: Would it mind saying $+ C$ instead of $+ O(1)$? And how do yo get to the conclussion that both integrals have the same magnitude?

Comment: @user3141592: just expand $-\log(1-w)$ as a Taylor series in a neighbourhood of $w=0$.